# I cannot enter double line breaks in PHP's mail() function

Tags: php, email

```
$text = 'blah<br /><br />blah';

$text = preg_replace('#<br />#', "\n", $text);
```

When I view it in the browser it does enter the double line breaks. However, when I try to send it to my email address via the `mail()` function it only outputs one line break.

Does anyone know what's the reason for this? And how to make it work?

And I am trying to send plain text, not html.

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `PHP_EOL` instead, for a cross-platform compatible solution, although `"\n"` should be 99% fine. Also, I'd suggest str_replace() instead of preg_replace(), parsing with regex (though as simple as this) is somewhat slower (*),

```
$text = "blah<br /><br />blah";  # with double quotes, not to have it treated literal.
$text = str_replace(array('<br />','<br/>','<br>'), PHP_EOL, $text);
```

(*) I'm waiting for critics about this

Comment: Preg_replace is great if you have long lists of items to search and replace, then it becomes worth the cost in processing power. For something like this str_replace would be sufficient, and faster. No criticism here for your advice.